# Interpretation of a Hermitian Operator Acting on a State Vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, quantum-measurements

In Susskind's Quantum Mechanics book The Theoretical Minimum, Eqn 3.21 on page 82 states that $\sigma_z |r\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|u\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|d\rangle$. He is clearing up confusion as to whether the operator acting on a state results in the state that we find upon measurement. He says this is definitely not the case since the $\sigma_z$ measurement would result in either +1 or -1 (so the state would either be $|u\rangle$ or $|d\rangle$, respectively). This makes sense.

Instead, it is suggested that the interpretation is that the $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|u\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|d\rangle$ is used simply for the calculation of probabilities (1/2 for $|u\rangle$ and 1/2 for $|d\rangle$ by squaring the magnitude of each corresponding coefficient). This still makes sense.

This makes me think of the eigenvalue equations: $\sigma_z|u\rangle=|u\rangle$ and $\sigma_z|d\rangle=-|d\rangle$. The above paragraph is consistent with this as well since the probabilities will simply be 1 for discovering it to be in the state it is already in.

My question is this: For a general eigenvalue equation $H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$, what happens to this interpretation if, say, $E=2$ (or anything greater than 1)? If we measure the observable $H$ while the system is in state $|\psi\rangle$, I suppose the interpretation suggests there is a 400% probability ($2\cdot2$) of discovering that the system is in state $|\psi\rangle$.

This interpretation seems to be very special to the Pauli matrices since their eigenvalues are only $\pm1$. I assume there is a simple explanation (do we have to normalize something?) but the book seems not to address it. Or maybe I am misunderstanding the interpretation altogether.

Comment: The probability to measure the value $E \in \mathbb R$ in the state $\psi$ is *not* $E$, even if $H\psi=E\psi$, where $H$ is the operator corresponding to the observable you measure. What the equation $H\psi=E\psi$ tells you instead is that $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$. This means that if you make a measurement of the observable corresponding to $H$, you will measure $E$ with certainty. This is an immediate consequence of the axioms of quantum mechanics, which I suggest you to look up (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is normalized but the action of an operator need not yield a normalized state.

In the specific example $H\vert \psi_n\rangle=E_n\vert \psi_n\rangle$, the multiple $E_n$ is the eigenvalue and the probability of getting the outcome $E_n$ is $1$.  This probability is obtained by expanding $\vert\psi_n\rangle$ as a sum of *all* orthonormalized eigenstates of $\hat H$:
$$
\vert \psi_n \rangle =\sum_k\vert\psi_{k}\rangle\langle \psi_k\vert\psi_n\rangle=\sum_k \vert\psi_k\rangle c_{k}\, ,\qquad c_k=\langle\psi_k\vert\psi_n\rangle.
$$
In your case, you have the probability $\vert c_n\vert^2$ of getting $E_n$ is $1$ since the only $c_k$ that is non-zero is $k=n$, and $c_n=\langle\psi_n\vert\psi_n\rangle=1$ since the eigenstates of $H$ are orthonormal.

Note how the coefficients $c_k$ *do not depend* on the eigenvalue $E_k$ although the particular coefficient you want, $c_n$, has the same label and the energy outcome of the measurement.

The example of Susskind is mildly confusing because the outcomes (i.e. the multiples) are coincidentally $\pm 1$, and multiplying a state buy $\pm 1$ does not change its norm.  In general, the outcomes of spin are taken to be $\pm \frac12$ (rather than $\pm 1$) so your logic would give probabilities of $\frac14$ in both cases and would not add to $1$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

> This interpretation seems to be very special to the Pauli matrices since their eigenvalues are only ±1. I assume there is a simple explanation (do we have to normalize something?) but the book seems not to address it. Or maybe I am misunderstanding the interpretation altogether.

You are misunderstanding the interpretation. If the state vector $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$, then a measurement of $H$ will yield $E$ with $100\%$ probability. The eigenvalue $E$ is irrelevant when computing the probability.

---

This may be more abstract than the OP is looking for, but I find the following to be a useful way of thinking. Consider the following procedure for defining an observable on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, and for simplicity and concreteness let our Hilbert space be $\mathbb C^2$.

Consider two orthogonal subspaces $V,W\subset \mathbb C^2$ (by orthogonal subspaces, I mean that if $\psi\in V$ and $\phi \in W$, then $\langle \psi,\phi\rangle = 0$).  For a concrete example, we might let
$$V = \left\{\lambda \pmatrix{1\\1} \ \bigg| \ \lambda \in \mathbb C\right\}$$
$$W = \left\{\lambda \pmatrix{-1\\1} \ \bigg| \ \lambda\in \mathbb C\right\}$$

Any vector in $\mathbb C^2$ can be uniquely expressed as the sum of an element of $V$ and an element of $W$.  For example,
$$\pmatrix{5\\7}= \pmatrix{6\\6} + \pmatrix{-1\\1} = \underbrace{6\pmatrix{1\\1}}_{\in V} + \underbrace{ \pmatrix{-1\\1}}_{\in W}$$

Next, we associate $\mathbb R$-valued numbers $\lambda_V$ and $\lambda_W$ with each subspace, which we interpret as possible measurement outcomes. To be concrete, let $\lambda_V=2$ and $\lambda_W = 6$. This defines an observable in the following sense:  Letting the state vector $\psi$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb C^2$, we may decompose it uniquely into $\psi = \psi_V + \psi_W$, where $\psi_V\in V$ and $\psi_W \in W$.  We now say that the probability of measuring our observable to have value $\lambda_V = 2$ is given by
$$\mathrm{Prob}(\lambda_V) = \frac{\Vert \psi_V \Vert^2}{ \Vert \psi\Vert^2}$$

while the probability of measuring our observable to have value $\lambda_W = 6$ is given by
$$\mathrm{Prob}(\lambda_W) = \frac{\Vert \psi_W \Vert^2}{ \Vert \psi\Vert^2}$$

Notice that we have constructed an observable and developed a recipe for computing the probability of the various measurement outcomes without ever making reference to a self-adjoint operator.

**However**, the structure we have defined *does* uniquely define a self-adjoint operator $\hat O$, which acts on an arbitrary vector $\psi\in \mathbb C^2$ by decomposing it into $\psi_V$ and $\psi_W$, scaling $\psi_V$ and $\psi_W$ by $\lambda_V$ and $\lambda_W$, respectively, and then adding them back together.  Explicitly,
$$\hat O \psi = \hat O(\psi_V + \psi_W) = \lambda_V \psi_V + \lambda_W \psi_W$$
In our concrete example, we would have

$$\hat O \pmatrix{5\\7} = \hat O\left(6\pmatrix{1\\1} + \pmatrix{-1\\1}\right) = \color{red}{2} \cdot 6 \pmatrix{1\\1} + \color{red}{6} \cdot\pmatrix{-1\\1}$$
$$ = \pmatrix{6\\18}$$
As an exercise for the reader, you might figure out how $\hat O$ acts on the vectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$, which yield the first and second columns of the matrix of $\hat O$; the result is
$$\hat O = \pmatrix{4 & -2 \\ -2 &4 }$$
which is self-adjoint, as promised.

---

In summary, for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces we can associate an observable with a decomposition of the Hilbert space into orthogonal subspaces ($V,W,\ldots$), each of which is associated with a possible measurement outcome ($\lambda_V,\lambda_W,\ldots$).  For an arbitrary state vector $\psi$, the probability of each measurement outcome is obtained by finding the component of $\psi$ which lies in the relevant subspace, taking its squared norm, and dividing the result by $\Vert\psi\Vert^2$.

Such a decomposition also defines a linear operator which acts on $\psi$ by decomposing it into its components in the various subspaces, scaling each component by the associated measurement outcome, and then adding them back together. This operator is guaranteed to be self-adjoint.

The crucial takeaway from this esoteric exercise is the claim that this goes both ways.  Just as a decomposition of the Hilbert space into subspaces with associated measurement outcomes uniquely defines a self-adjoint operator, every self-adjoint operator uniquely defines a decomposition of the Hilbert space into subspaces (given by its eigenspaces) with associated measurement outcomes (its eigenvalues).

From this point of view, when we associate an observable with a self-adjoint operator $\hat O$, the importance of $\hat O$ is **not** in how it acts on vectors, but rather in the decomposition of the Hilbert space and associated measurement outcomes which it defines.